# how to pass filter parameters in url from Tableau or tabjolt

Tags: url, filter, tableau-api

Below is the link which has examples for how to pass parameters in URL in Tableau.
https://community.tableau.com/thread/104580

But i have a filter in dashboard where i can select Last 5 Years[image]

While i want to apply same filter from URL what is the syntax???

i need to run dashboards from tabjolt and tabjolt only accepts URL. if there is any way to configure filters for views in tabjolt that will also be a great help

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing in an actual date in ISO 8601 format, such as `?Appointment%20Date>2016-06-20`

I'm not sure whether that will interfere with the relative date filter you have on your view or not, but if so, you could build your own relative date filter with a couple of parameters - say an integer representing the number of previous time units and a string representing the time unit (month, day, year etc)

Might not be as flexible as the built-in relative date filter, but the URL parameter behavior can then be made to act however you like.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, i'll try that